# Remove all occurrences from an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an NSSTring that is HTML and I need to remove all of the opening and closing `strong` tags

How would I go through the string an delete all of the `<strong>` and `</strong>`?

Comment: Use NSString method stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:. Go though NSString apple doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using  **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString**: method of **NSString**

```
NSString *newString = nil;
NSString *resultString = nil;
newString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<strong>" withString:@""];
resultString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</strong>" withString:@""];
```

The above code assumes no white space in the html tags to be removed, where **resultString** represents the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the string by using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString .

```
NSString *resultString = nil;
resultString = [[htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<strong>" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</strong>" withString:@""];
```

or can be use as regular expression

```
NSRange r;
  NSString *s =@"Html String";
  while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

check it with scanner

```
-(NSString *)convertHTML:(NSString *)html {

NSScanner *myScanner;
NSString *text = nil;
myScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

while ([myScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

    [myScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ;

    [myScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
}
//
html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

return html;
}
```